# OS X Yosemite - cannot remember Keychain access password

Tags: password

Is there any way to recover this?  Can I change it without knowing my current password?

Answer (score 1):

No. You cannot recover the contents of the keychain without the password. There is no way to reset the password retaining the keychain data.

---

If you want to access a login keychain after changing user's password, the keychain will still be accessible using the old password.

If the problem is reappearing password prompt after a login password change, you can delete and recreate the keychain, but the original data is non-recoverable.